# Best way of importing a large data file to MysQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have an application which receives a datafile of size **16GB** (with around **90,00,000 lines**) which is to be imported into a MySQL database. Everytime I ran the php script, I would get the error **'Lost connection to MySQL server during query** even though the database is on the same server where the script is running.

After searching on the internet I found out that this happens when you exhaust **one resource for the db session,** such as memory, and mysql closes the connection.The idea is that the transaction you're running shouldn't try to insert a large amount of data. And that you can work around this by setting a higher value to 'max_allowed_packet'. I did this in my script itself:

`$db->query( 'SET @@global.max_allowed_packet = ' . 1 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024);`

But this doesn't work either. Except that the error occurs after inserting a significantly higher number of rows.'

Now I am splitting the file into smaller files with 10,00,000 lines each and then processing each of them. But even the splitting takes a considerable amount of time.

I am not a PHP programmer, nor have I worked with MySQL before. This is someone else's code that I have to refactor. So my knowledge here is almost zero.

I am using the `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` statement to dump the data. Is there any way of making the transactions shorter by committing after every few lines?

Comment: You can try importing using command prompt or using third party dumping scripts like [bigdump](http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/).

Comment: Sounds more like a timeout rather than memory issue with the session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote my own dump script, based on the same lines as BigDump. It takes three command line argumens:

1. Fully qualified file name which is to be dumped
2. Table in which to be dumped
3. After how many rows are loaded should the transaction be commited.

> 

```
<?php
    function GetCommaSeparatedValues($row) //Creates a comma separated list of all the column - values in the row
    {
        $str = '';
        $str =  '\'' . addslashes(substr($row,0,12)) . '\',' . //addslashes() escapes special characters with a '\' 
                '\'' . addslashes(substr($row,12,12)) . '\',' .
                '\'' . addslashes(substr($row,24,2)) . '\',' .
                '\'' . addslashes(substr($row,26,24)) . '\',' .
                '\'' . addslashes(substr($row,50,05)) . '\'';
        return str;
    }

    function print_error($err, $linenumber, $pk)
    {
        echo $err . ' at line number: ' . $linenumber . PHP_EOL;
    }

    ini_set('display_errors',1); 
    ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
    error_reporting(E_ERROR); //Report only those errors that are fatal runtime errors
    ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'); //Allow script to use maximum available memory
    $query="";
    $totalqueries=$argv[3]; //Commit after loading how many lines
    $linenumber=0;
    $currenttotal=0;
    $handle = fopen($argv[1], "r"); //File to dump in database
    $tablename = $argv[2]; //table name of the db in which to dump file

    $con=mysqli_connect("db1","root","N3@k83@rd","pov2013p_pov");

    $lno = 0;
    $tempquery = 'SET @@global.max_allowed_packet = ' . 1 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
    mysqli_query($con,$tempquery);
    mysqli_autocommit($con,FALSE);
    if ($handle)
    {
            echo `date` . 'Importing file: ' . $argv[1] . PHP_EOL ;
            echo 'Commit after every '. $totalqueries . ' lines. ' . PHP_EOL;
            echo 'Dumping into table '. $tablename . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;

            while (($dumpline = fgets($handle)) !== false)
            {
                                            $lno++;
                    if($currenttotal == $totalqueries)
                    {
                            echo `date` . 'Commiting at line number: ' . $linenumber . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
                                                            mysqli_commit($con);
                            $currenttotal=0;
                            if($temp)
                            {
                                    while(mysqli_next_result($con))
                                    {
                                            if($result = mysqli_store_result($con))
                                            {
                                                    while($r = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
                                                    {
                                                            echo('*');
                                                    }
                                            }
                                    }
                            }

                    }
                    $commaseparated = commaseparatedvalues($dumpline);
                    $query = 'INSERT INTO pov2013p_pov.'.$tablename.' VALUES ('. $commaseparated .');';

                    mysqli_query($con,$query) or print_error(mysqli_error($con),$lno,substr($dumpline,0,12));
                    $currenttotal++;
                    $linenumber++;

            }
            if($query!='')
            {
                    echo `date` . 'Commiting at line number: ' . $linenumber . PHP_EOL;
                    mysqli_commit($con);
            }

            echo `date` . 'Finished Import.' . PHP_EOL;

    }
    else
    {
            echo "Cannot open file";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You really need to make use of [**`BigDump`**](http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/)

> Staggered import of large and very large MySQL Dumps (like phpMyAdmin
>   2.x dumps) even through the web servers with hard runtime limit and those in safe mode.

To configure it.. See [`here`](http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/you-need/) or [`here`](http://wesbos.com/import-large-mysql-database-bigdump-php/)

Comment: nice,upvote.but why should not use command line as in my answer.

Comment: Your command line example only works for sql dumps. The OP is using load data local infile which suggests a csv(ish) format. mysqiimport would work in that case.

Comment: Yes, I am importing the data from a plain text file. This import needs to happen automatically once every month. Can I call this BigDump tool through a script? Or does it have to be run from a command line?

Comment: @mridula, You can directly run from the script. See here http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/usage/

Answer (score -2):

Here is how you can import in the command line, you can import large files this way:

```
mysql -hyourhostname-uusername -p databasename < yoursqlfile.sql
```